# Textures are not visible on material preview mode

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, interface

As can be seen below the textures on the presents are not visible on material preview mode but visible on the render preview.

[image]

I've tried to pack resources with (File → External Data → Pack resources) and tried to find missing files with (File → External Data → Find missing Files) showing the textures location but still I can't see the textures on material preview mode.

[image]

Do you have any idea about what I am missing here?

[image]

[image]

Here is the properties screenshot of the missing image
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please pack your image and share one of your boxes? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: What do you mean by pack your image? I guess I've clicked everything on External Data menu but the issue still not resolved...

Comment: @ycp I think moonboots means share your file with us (just one of the boxes for simplicity) after doing external data > pack resources so we can take a look, not that packing should fix your issue

Comment: Yes I meant pack the resources, which seems to be the case but I just want to be sure that you'll share the textures as well  ;)

Comment: It seems I am a total noob :) I'm unpacking the blend file to share it but it is still 80mb. And even if I try to export one of the boxes as stl or fbx when i import it to a new scene it seems it adds all of the scene with tree and other stuff :(

Comment: @ycp try just copy pasting one of the boxes to a new blender file? check if the error is still there and share that if it is. Or you could delete everything else in your file, search for and run "purge all > recursive (in the bottom left panel that pops up)", then save that as a new file and share?

Comment: okay I've uploaded it and now textures are not visible on the rendered view as well

Comment: @ycp You need to share the link it generates when you uploaded it. Edit your answer and add it to the end.

Comment: okay now it is downloadable

Comment: Thanks, you haven't packed your image though. If I use another image, it seems to work fine though. Could you please pack, save, and share again?

Comment: @moonboots The texture shows up in Cycles though, I don't think it's a problem of packing (texture doesn't show in UV or Image editors, however—but you can save as it to your computer!). I suspect it's something to do with UDIMs, but idk what exactly. I actually got it to show in Eevee when doing undos randomly, but couldn't replicate. Some kind of bug perhaps, not sure.

Comment: Oh ok I couldn't see it, it's probably a problem of format, it is currently 8 bit, if I convert it  to 16 bit-float it works fine in both Eevee and Cycles

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem of format, it is currently 8 bit, which makes it invisible in Eevee and in *Material Preview*. If you save your image as *16-bit float* it will work fine.

Comment: Where do you see it's an 8-bit image? Do you convert it to 16 in Blender itself, or in an external image editor?

Comment: ok how can I do that? I've changed Color Depth value 8 to 16 on output properties is that it?

Comment: I've unpacked the image, opened it in Krita and saw that it was 8 bit, I converted it in Krita

Comment: I've unwrapped the cubes with cube projection is this related to that? Also I've tried to change the float to 16bit from the output properties and saved the file but after reopening the file I still could not see the image on material preview.

Comment: Could you share your file again?

Comment: Are you sure that the image that is used by your material is the good one (16-bit) and not the previous one (8-bit)?

Comment: yes all of the images I've used on the presents are above 16bit, I've shared the file again

Comment: I've unpacked the image of your new file and again it's 8 bit, you need to make sure that you've selected a 16 bit in your Image Editor

Comment: I am so confused, I've checked the image properties and it seems 24 bit. I've attached a screenshot of it.

Comment: Maybe try to open it in an image editor like Photoshop and convert it to 16 or 32 bit?

Comment: @moonboots I unpacked the image, converted it to16-bit in Krita, saved, then refreshed and packed it in Blender. Didn't change a thing. Did you import the unpacked image as a new one back into Blender? If so, I don't think it works because of bit-depth, because when you re-import, it works if you haven't done anything to it at all. I still suspect sth about UDIMs but not sure.

Comment: I've changed the bit depth of the image 8 to 16 on photoshop, created a new material on the cube and added the new image to the shared blend file and adjusted the output properties to 8 bit again but the texture still not visible on material or rendered view.

Comment: I unpack, open in Krita, convert to 16-Bit, then load in the Image Texture node, it works. If I save in Krita as 8-Bit image I'll still won't see anything. But there might be another problem...